Host server that runs python script with preloaded data
I have a python script (let's suppose it's a single file) that has 3 sections:
(1) load external libraries
(2) load a large file's contents
(3) algorithm
While section (3) takes 100 milliseconds, sections (1) and (2) take 10 seconds.
I have a C# program that executes the Python script above:
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pythonPath, fileNameWithArg)
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };
        process.Start();

        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

I am passing some arguments and waiting for a response from the Python script, as you can see above.
How can I make my implementation better so that my Python script's sections (1) and (2) don't have to load with each subsequent call? I am only interested in the actual algorithm (section 3) because sections (1) and (2) are constant. Therefore, rather than waiting an additional 10 seconds for sections (1) and (2) to finish, I would prefer to call my Python script and receive a response after 100ms.I am happy for the first call to python script to take 10 second +, but every consecutive call should take 100 ms only.

You can make the Python script running persistently, run (1) once, and keep (2) in process memory.
Then you can use inter-process communication like named pipes to communicate between the Python process and .NET process.
